# How to use sed or other commands to replace existing string with a different string for each line

Tags: linux, bash

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do
 sed "s/\number\b/& =$i/" print.txt 
done
```

print.txt contains:

```
number elephant
number giraffe
number dogs
number cats
number mouse
number pigs
number snake
```

How do I replace a word/string in ONE line of a text file in a for loop without changing every line? Whenever I run my script it makes all the 'number' into one specific number and by the time the last iteration runs, all the 'number' is replaced by 7. I understand why it does that, just not sure how to fix it.

In this simple example, I want it to be outputted like this:

```
1 elephant
2 giraffe
3 dogs
4 cats
5 mouse
6 pigs
7 snake
```

But let's say, in my for loop, it defines a variable to be goat and the second iteration to be chicken, I want pigs to be changed to goat and snake to be changed to chicken, how do I do that inside my for loop?

Comment: `in ONE line` - which line? The `number dogs` one or `number snake` one? Please post the expected output you want the program to produce for the input provided.

Comment: if you're only replacing the text in ONE line, what's the purpose of the `for` loop?  I agree with KamilCuk ... please update the question with the expected results

Comment: In this example, I want the expected output to be:
1 elephant
2 giraffe
3 dogs
.... etc

Comment: Another approach: `awk '{print NR,$2}' file` or `awk '$1=NR' file`

Comment: your additional question (switching animal names) should be a separate question, and should include input, what you've tried so far, and the desired output

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to replace `"number"` in each line with increasing values `1-7`, then you don't need (or want) a loop at all. Simply pipe the result of `sed` removing the `"number"` string from the beginning of each line to `nl -w1 -s' '` to number the lines. Example:

```
$ sed 's/^number\s*//' print.txt | nl -w1 -s' '
1 elephant
2 giraffe
3 dogs
4 cats
5 mouse
6 pigs
7 snake
```

(**note:** you can use `grep -o '\w*$' print.txt | nl -w1 -s' '` as well)

You can adjust the number format and separator with options. See [man 1 nl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nl.1.html).

Why don't you want a loop? How many times are you invoking `sed` and spawning an additional subshell within your loop? (one per-iteration). This is horribly inefficient. Any time you are looping in shell, you want to minimize the number of subshells spawned within your loop.

Can you do it with a loop as you were attempting? Of course, but it is one of the least efficient solutions you could come up with. To make it work in a loop, you have to limit your operation per-iteration to the wanted line in the file. You can do that by suppressing normal output and only outputting the line you changed, e.g.

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7; do
    sed -n "${i}s/number/$i/p" print.txt
done
```

(*but DON'T do it this way...*)

If you want an even more efficient solution that eliminates the pipe and additional subshell, just use `awk` and a counter (`n` below), e.g.

```
$ awk -v n=1 '{print n++ " " $2}' print.txt
1 elephant
2 giraffe
3 dogs
4 cats
5 mouse
6 pigs
7 snake
```

You can likewise further control the number and separator format using `printf` instead of `print` above.

Let me know if you have questions or if you are wanting something different.

---

**Answer to Comment Question**

If you have 3 lines with an identical field you want to change to something else, you first have to know what you want to change the identical fields to. That means you must have a *replacement table* or *lookup table* of replacements somewhere.

Say your text file is actually:

```
$ cat print2.txt
number elephant
number giraffe
number dogs
number cats
number pigs
number pigs
number pigs
```

And you want to change lines 5, 6, 7 from `"pigs"` to `"goat", "cow", "chicken"` in that order, then with `awk` you can read the replacement values into an array and make the replacements using a counter to determine which replacement to use. (below we just fill an array with the three replacements)

You can do something similar to the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=1; rep[1]="goat"; rep[2]="cow"; rep[3]="chicken"}
    $2=="pigs"{$2=rep[n++]}
    {print}
' print2.txt
```

Copy/pasting at the command line would yield:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {n=1; rep[1]="goat"; rep[2]="cow"; rep[3]="chicken"}
>     $2=="pigs"{$2=rep[n++]}
>     {print}
> ' print2.txt
number elephant
number giraffe
number dogs
number cats
number goat
number cow
number chicken
```

So you can do what you ask in the comment -- you just need to know what you will replace repeats by in advance.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the response, the number thing was just an example for a simple for loop. If I wanted to replace something that appears in every line of a text file in a for loop, how would I go about accomplishing that?
Let's say line 5, 6, 7 are all pigs but I want to replace it with goat, cow, chicken, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: See the update -- the key is to only operate on one line per-iteration. Any time you want to replace a *FIELD* in a line -- `awk` is the goto Swiss-Army Knife of text processing. `sed` is very good working on *streams* (or lines themselves), but not so great at *fields*.

Comment: @yoyo31 see additional edit for `"goat", "cow", "chicken"` replacement.

Answer (score 0):

A pure bash shell solution without any external tools/utility.

```
!/bin/bash

n=1
while read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "${line//number/"$n"}"
  ((n++))
done < print.txt
```

Using POSIX sh.

```
#!/bin/sh

n=1
while read -r line; do
  printf '%d. %s\n' "$n" "${line#* }"
  n=$((n+1))
done < print.txt
```

For a small size/set of data/input it should be fine.